# Amazon polly not reading first word/its not audible in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-polly

I have used amazon polly Joanna in my iOS application, but I m not able to hear first one word of the text I entered. can anyone please help me in solving this issue. 
Bellow is the code I m using

```
let input = AWSPollySynthesizeSpeechURLBuilderRequest()

// Text to synthesize
input.text = "Sample text"

// We expect the output in MP3 format
input.outputFormat = AWSPollyOutputFormat.mp3

// Choose the voice ID
input.voiceId = AWSPollyVoiceId.joanna

// Create an task to synthesize speech using the given synthesis input
let builder = AWSPollySynthesizeSpeechURLBuilder.default().getPreSignedURL(input)

// Request the URL for synthesis result
builder.continueOnSuccessWith(block: { (awsTask: AWSTask<NSURL>) -> Any? in
    // The result of getPresignedURL task is NSURL.
    // Again, we ignore the errors in the example.
    let url = awsTask.result!

    // Try playing the data using the system AVAudioPlayer
    self.audioPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(url: url as URL))
    self.audioPlayer.play()

    return nil
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you listening through a bluetooth device? 
Often times those devices go into idle mode and have a startup time. You do not have the ability to control the user's bluetooth device, you can load a short MP3 of silence into an AVPlayer and play shortly before you need the speech. Or, you can set up a notification center task to loop playback while your device runs:

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: myPlayer.currentItem, queue: nil) { (_) in
    myPlayer.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
    myPlayer.play()
}
```

Here's a silent mp3 you can use:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0h6cdqx9yvbw2xs/silence.mp3?dl=0